# Removing the default hover effect of a button

Tags: c#, winforms, button, hover

I am trying to apply a color to a hovered button like this:

```
private void button_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
    button.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.GradientInactiveCaption;
}

private void button_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
    button.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlLight;
}
```

My Problem is there seems to be some kind of a default hover effect. The color is much darker than it should be. At the moment I do not know where to start to get rid of it.

Comment: Every control has its own template, in that templates you can edit how a button behaves on events like mouse enter, leave, click etc.. Search for that. And, what version of VS are you using?

Comment: VS 2013 Ultimate Update 3

Comment: @jackjop He's using Winforms, not some XAML based framework.

Comment: don't suppose setting your button style to flat is an option?

Comment: something like: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3475826/3436942

Comment: Instead of fighting with the existing Button class you can just create a custom control. Replicating button behavior is very easy.

Comment: Thx alot jbutler483 that one works well.